# Identifying Sides of a Tetrahedron

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In a homework question I was asked to figure out what sort of object you get from identifying pairs of sides of a tetrahedron. If the tetra hedron has verticies a, b , c and d and we make the identifications abc~bcd and cad~adb (where in abc~bcd a goes to b, b goes to c etc...). Rather than asking what sort of object this is I would like to have some sort of hint maybe on how to approach this problem as I have a lot of trouble visualizing whats going on here.

Comment: I imagine you already know each of the answers in the case of a (plane) rectangle, do you?

Comment: It is also not clear to me what happens in the case of identifying triangles in a rectangle and i do not see how this relates to a tetrahedron.

Comment: I meant glueing opposite edges, as in [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rectangle.html).

Comment: if you glue opposite edges you can get a lot of different things depending on how you glue it; a torus, klein bottle, rp2 etc ...

Comment: I understand how to do this now; seems like the way to go is to think about at as a cell complex and seeing stuff will be identified.

Comment: When you are done you may post your own solution so someone else in need can find it.